# "System.Dynamic - Invalid argument" on second and succeeding Document.ExecCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, execcommand

Have a WPF app using the WebBrowser control.  It uses Document.ExecCommand() to copy the HTML of the displayed page to the clipboard and then stores that in a variable:

XAML

`<WebBrowser x:Name="browser"... />`

Code-behind

```
browser.Source = new Uri(selectedUrl);

dynamic document = browser.Document;
document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", true, null);
document.ExecCommand("Copy", true, null);
document.ExecCommand("Unselect", true, null);

IDataObject iDataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
var content = iDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
```

This all works fine the first time.  But after navigating to a second URL within the same session, on the Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", true, null), it throws an exception of

```
{"Invalid argument."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146827850 (0x800A01B6)
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Invalid argument."
    Source: "System.Dynamic"
    StackTrace:
        at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
        at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , String , Boolean , Object )
        at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Boolean , Object )
        ...
    TargetSite: {Void CheckThrowException(Int32, System.Dynamic.ExcepInfo ByRef, UInt32, System.String)}
```

However, this doesn't happen all the time.  One time I can test and it works on the first and every other page I bring up after that.  The next time I test, it throws the exception.

Comment: Why do you use `dynamic`?

Comment: @bc004346 Everything I've read indicates you have to use dynamic because the underlying object is mshtml.HtmlDocumentClass -- a COM object -- and requires this for access.

Comment: Is your goal to copy the HTML from a webpage or to copy the text from a webpage and then convert that to HTML?

Comment: I am asking because it looks like you are doing the latter with your code.

Comment: Also, when are you getting this property? If you are getting the value of this property before the page loads, I suspect that may cause your problem.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: The page is already loaded when this event occurs.  You're correct that it is copying the content.  Then the content is subsequently loaded into an HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument for processing.  But the error happens in just attempting to capture the content from the page.

Comment: Okay, try something for me. Go ahead and add a COM reference to the Microsoft HTML Object library and then store the Document as an MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 before doing your execCommand. I have seen other people get weird Dynamic exceptions on second time runs if they didn't cast it first.

Comment: I am referencing this post as an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051279/notsupportedexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-exception?rq=1

Comment: Using mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document and then processing that variable seems to have resolved the situation.  I've been able to process multiple pages in the same session.  If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.